# How to escape special characters when echoing variable in Bash script?

Tags: bash, special-characters

Fellow StackOverflow,

How should I handle escaping special characters in a string like this:

```
^VfAro@khm=Y)@5,^AyxPO[[$2jW#+Vg;Paj2ycIj8VUr5z1,}qR~JnK7r_0@$ov
```

I am using this string in a variable which is piped to `cryptsetup luksOpen` inside the Bash script:

```
echo "${string}" | cryptsetup luksOpen UUID={...}
```

But when executing the script, I got some characters stripped. When echoing the *plain* string, all the characters are preserved.

I have tried with different variable enclosing as well as with *printf "%q"* but without any viable result.

Comment: I suspect you're using `string="^VfAro@khm=Y)@5,^AyxPO[[$2jW#+Vg;Paj2ycIj8VUr5z1,}qR~JnK7r_0@$ov"`. If so, you may using single quote instead of double quote as `string='^VfAro@khm=Y)@5,^AyxPO[[$2jW#+Vg;Paj2ycIj8VUr5z1,}qR~JnK7r_0@$ov'`

Comment: `printf '%s\n'`. Only use `%q` when generating code that's intended to be `eval`-safe.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you *do* want a trailing newline on the input to `cryptsetup`:

```
s='^VfAro@khm=Y)@5,^AyxPO[[$2jW#+Vg;Paj2ycIj8VUr5z1,}qR~JnK7r_0@$ov'
printf '%s\n' "$s" | cryptsetup luksOpen
```

#### If you *don't* want a trailing newline:

```
s='^VfAro@khm=Y)@5,^AyxPO[[$2jW#+Vg;Paj2ycIj8VUr5z1,}qR~JnK7r_0@$ov'
printf '%s' "$s" | cryptsetup luksOpen
```

#### In both cases, *we don't use `echo`* when we care about byte-for-byte perfect output.

Comment: ... and if the OP has a single quote ' in the expression ... this will still work without a backslash escape ?!

Comment: Inside single quotes, *everything except another single quote* is literal (meaning, evaluating exactly to itself).

Comment: Note that there are two separate problems solved here, *setting* the variable correctly (as above, single quotes are usually simplest, but it depends on what special characters are in the string), and *printing* the variable correctly (`printf` is almost always the right answer here).